# how do I order by the results of multiple union statements?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-order-by, common-table-expression

I can't use a common table expression:

```
WITH    cte
          AS (SELECT    [StationID],
                        [LastDistribution]
              FROM      [DB1].[dbo].[ProcessingStations]
              UNION ALL
              SELECT    [StationID],
                        [LastDistribution]
              FROM      [DB2].[dbo].[ProcessingStations]
              UNION ALL
              SELECT    [StationID],
                        [LastDistribution]
              FROM      [DB3].[dbo].[ProcessingStations]
              UNION ALL
              SELECT    [StationID],
                        [LastDistribution]
              FROM      [DB4].[dbo].[ProcessingStations]
              UNION ALL
              SELECT    [StationID],
                        [LastDistribution]
              FROM      [DB5].[dbo].[ProcessingStations]
              ORDER BY  [StationID]
              UNION ALL
              SELECT    [StationID],
                        [LastDistribution]
              FROM      [DB6].[dbo].[ProcessingStations]
              UNION ALL
              SELECT    [StationID],
                        [LastDistribution]
              FROM      [DB7].[dbo].[ProcessingStations]
              UNION ALL
              SELECT    [StationID],
                        [LastDistribution]
              FROM      [DB8].[dbo].[ProcessingStations])
    SELECT  *
    FROM    cte
    ORDER BY StationID
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: how will the records be ordered?

Comment: from the lowest station number to the highest among all of the tables in the unions.

Comment: Put the `ORDER BY` at the very end. ex: `SELECT ... UNION SELECT ... UNION SELECT ... ORDER BY ...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put the `ORDER BY` at the end of your chain of `SELECT ... FROM ... UNION ALL` statements:

```
SELECT    [StationID],
          [LastDistribution]
          FROM      [DB1].[dbo].[ProcessingStations]
          UNION ALL
          SELECT    [StationID],
                    [LastDistribution]
          FROM      [DB2].[dbo].[ProcessingStations]
          UNION ALL
          SELECT    [StationID],
                    [LastDistribution]
          FROM      [DB3].[dbo].[ProcessingStations]
          UNION ALL
          SELECT    [StationID],
                    [LastDistribution]
          FROM      [DB4].[dbo].[ProcessingStations]
          UNION ALL
          SELECT    [StationID],
                    [LastDistribution]
          FROM      [DB5].[dbo].[ProcessingStations]
          ORDER BY  [StationID]
          UNION ALL
          SELECT    [StationID],
                    [LastDistribution]
          FROM      [DB6].[dbo].[ProcessingStations]
          UNION ALL
          SELECT    [StationID],
                    [LastDistribution]
          FROM      [DB7].[dbo].[ProcessingStations]
          UNION ALL
          SELECT    [StationID],
                    [LastDistribution]
          FROM      [DB8].[dbo].[ProcessingStations]
ORDER BY StationID
```

Here's a quick example I did in SSMS:

```
DECLARE @a table (x int)
DECLARE @b table (x int)
DECLARE @c table (x int)

insert into @a values (5)
insert into @a values (4)
insert into @a values (3)

insert into @b values (0)
insert into @b values (1)
insert into @b values (2)

insert into @c values (0)
insert into @c values (1)
insert into @c values (2)

select * from @a
union all
select * from @b
union all
select * from @c
order by x
```

And here's the output:

```
  x
-----
  0
  0
  1
  1
  2
  2
  3
  4
  5
```

As you can see, even though the `SELECT * FROM @a` came first, it still placed those last in the result set

Comment: this does not work. it only orders the last table in the union.

Comment: @Rj. - that's incorrect. The `ORDER BY` at the end of a chain of `UNION` or `UNION ALL`s applies an ordering to the *entire* `UNION`.

Comment: @Rj, I added an example I did locally. It worked fine, from what I could tell.

Answer (score 4):

Why can't you use a `CTE`?. Anyway, you still can do the same using a derived table:

```
SELECT *
FROM (  SELECT    [StationID],
                  [LastDistribution]
        FROM      [DB1].[dbo].[ProcessingStations]
        UNION ALL
        SELECT    [StationID],
                  [LastDistribution]
        FROM      [DB2].[dbo].[ProcessingStations]
        UNION ALL
        SELECT    [StationID],
                  [LastDistribution]
        FROM      [DB3].[dbo].[ProcessingStations]
        UNION ALL
        SELECT    [StationID],
                  [LastDistribution]
        FROM      [DB4].[dbo].[ProcessingStations]
        UNION ALL
        SELECT    [StationID],
                  [LastDistribution]
        FROM      [DB5].[dbo].[ProcessingStations]
        UNION ALL
        SELECT    [StationID],
                  [LastDistribution]
        FROM      [DB6].[dbo].[ProcessingStations]
        UNION ALL
        SELECT    [StationID],
                  [LastDistribution]
        FROM      [DB7].[dbo].[ProcessingStations]
        UNION ALL
        SELECT    [StationID],
                  [LastDistribution]
        FROM      [DB8].[dbo].[ProcessingStations]) A
ORDER BY StationID
```

Comment: im getting this error with what you said (by the way, i wasnt the downvoter) - Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 22
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 33
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: @Rj. What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 10.50.4000. That's SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 2.

Comment: @Rj. Sorry, didn't notice you had an `ORDER BY` on one of the sub selects. Try the updated code.

Comment: @Rj. your server should support CTE. It was introduce back on SQL Server 2005. What do you mean by you can't use? Someone doesn't allows you to use it?

Comment: that's my bad. i forgot to remove the order by in the midde of the query. it's working thanks and sorry about the confusion!

Answer (score 0):

See the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/924c6/1), just put the `ORDER BY` on the last set to be "unioned". It achieves the same result without the overhead of the CTE.

The order will effect the entire unified set.

```
SELECT
        [StationID],
        [LastDistribution]
    FROM 
        [dbo].[ProcessingStations]
UNION ALL
SELECT
        [StationID],
        [LastDistribution]
    FROM 
        [dbo].[ProcessingStations]
UNION ALL
SELECT
        [StationID],
        [LastDistribution]
    FROM 
        [dbo].[ProcessingStations]
    ORDER BY
        [StationID]
```